# MapReduce Debugging: How can I check the current Mapper's ID in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

For debugging purposes, I want to check which `mapper` is currently working on which part of the data. I would like to print out the **mapper ID** of the current worker in Hadoop.

Is it possible to access the `Mapper` or `Reducer`'s information?

I am expecting something like

```
this.current_mapper.info
or
context.mapper.info
```

Comment: Your data is distributed into multiple splits stored as blocks on HDFS. So, you want to know which mapper works on a particular data split?

Comment: Yes, I want to know check something like mapper_20 is working on which part and mapper_21 is working on which part.

Comment: I understand that the point of MapReduce implementation is that the program should not be depending on each `worker` but I want to know it for the **debugging** purposes.